# <c:foreach jsp iterate over list

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have searched several examples, still have not get. I am passing an List of GOOD object from controller into jsp pages. trying to loop over the list object, but its showing only one element repeatedly. should I use beans? If yes, could you provide more specific example for my case.

```
 <c:if test="${not empty listGood}">
     <c:forEach var="ob" varStatus="status" items="${listGood}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${ob.name}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ob.measure}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ob.quantity}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ob.price}"/></td>
    </tr>
             </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
```

**Update**
Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/supply"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String consumptFormulate(Locale locale, Model model, @ModelAttribute ConsumptionForm cmd, HttpServletRequest request){
  String[] s_str =cmd.getFromDate().split("/");
  String normal_s  = s_str[2]+"-"+s_str[0]+"-"+s_str[1];
  String[] f_str = cmd.getToDate().split("/");
   String normal_f  = f_str[2]+"-"+f_str[0]+"-"+f_str[1];
     List<Good> list = service.getGoods(normal_s,normal_f,cmd.getSocGoods(),cmd.getTradeObj());
     List<ListGoodsForm> listg = new ArrayList<ListGoodsForm>();
     org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries series = new org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries("За месяц:");
     if(!list.isEmpty()){
         lg=list;
         ListGoodsForm listo = new ListGoodsForm();
         java.util.Calendar ca = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

         for(Good g: list){
             listo.setName(g.getName());
             listo.setMeasure(g.getMeasure());
             listo.setPrice(g.getPrice());
             listo.setQuantity(g.getQuantity());
             listg.add(listo);
             java.util.Date date = g.getDates();
             java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
              ca.setTime(date);
             int in = ca.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
                 String month = format.format(date);
        }
            }
       request.setAttribute("listGood",listg);
     //model.addAttribute("listGood", listg);
     model.addAttribute("GOODS", prepareDataList());
    // model.add
     model.addAttribute("COMPANY",sservice.getSupplierName());
     model.addAttribute("consumptionForm", cmd);

   return "supply";  
}
```

Comment: how do you pass value to `listGood`?

Comment: I don't see any mistake on your JSP page. Maybe the problem is in your Controller, make sure the list is properly added onto your JSP. does the JSP show some errors? or just a blank without output within the given code block?
if it's blank, then your list is empty, or remove the varStatus :) hope it helps

Comment: And how many items `listGood` should have? Maybe there is an interpreter which modifies the list.

Comment: are you sure your list have one or more records.. ????

Comment: Spring mvc, passing from model objects. but it shows only one element which is repeated.

Comment: Am passing it as model.add("listGood", listg); is it correct?

Comment: @ManishNagar yeah, it is returning records, but only one record is displayed which is repeated. I am passing to jsp like this from controller model.add("listGood",listg);

Comment: use this request.setAttribute("listGood",listg);

Comment: and tell me in list you have different types of records not duplicate records ?

Comment: post your servlet code .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your controller is doing the following:

```
Good g = new Good();
List<Good> goods = new ArrayList<Good>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    g.setName("a");
    ...
    goods.add(g);
}
```

This means that you're modifying the same Good object 4 tilmes, and adding it 4 times to the list. In the end, your have 4 times the same object, containing the state you set into it in the last iteration.

Instead, do this:

```
List<Good> goods = new ArrayList<Good>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Good g = new Good();
    g.setName("a");
    ...
    goods.add(g);
}
```

EDIT : and your edited question just confirmed my guess:

```
ListGoodsForm listo = new ListGoodsForm();
```

this line should be inside the for loop, and not outside.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to pass list

```
 request.setAttribute("listGood",listg);
```

Comment: there is no duplicate records, tried you answer but it is not working, for example if list contains 4 records, it will display 4 times and in each of them only first row is displayed. Do you think to use Bean?