# JSP access methods of objects in a list

Tags: java, jsp, object, arraylist

I have 2 java classes. One is a java bean and the other is a collection of instances from this java bean class.

```
public class Quiz{ 
  private int id;
  private String title;
  //getters and setters 
}

public class Quizzes{
  List<Quiz> quizList = new ArrayList<Quiz>;
  public Quizzes{
    //constructor to add Quiz objects to quizList
    Quiz curQuiz = new Quiz();
    ...
  }
  public List<Quiz> getQuizList(){
    return this.quizList;
  }

}
```

In my JSP I want to access for example the id (or title) of a Quiz. How can I do this? The only Idea I have is to iterate over the Objects in quizlist and call getId Method, and then add this Integer Values to a List. For example like this:

```
public List<Integer> getId(){
    List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ListIterator<Quiz> ir = quizlist.listIterator();
    int id;
    while (ir.hasNext()){
        Quiz curQuiz = ir.next();
        id = curQuiz.getId();
        idList.add(id);
    }
    return idList;
}
```

But isn't there a better solution?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have this quizList (ArrayList of Quiz objects). In my JSP I want to output the ids of every Quiz object from my quizList.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into `<jsp:useBean>` tag. The syntax for the same is

```
<jsp:useBean id= "attributeName" scope= "page | request | session | application" class= "yourPackage.yourClass"> </jsp:useBean>.
```

here `attributeName` is the name of attribute you have set in `page, request, session or application scope`.
`yourPackage.yourClass` is your beanClass i.e. `Quiz` if you want to access `Quiz` member variables.

You can find good example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/UseBean.shtml)

If you want to iterate over a list which is accessible in jsp, then you can use `forEach` tag.

[<c:foreach jsp iterate over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053052/cforeach-jsp-iterate-over-list)

```
<c:forEach var="window" items="${requestScope.quizList}">
    <c:out value="${quiz.id}"/> 
    <c:out value="${quiz.name}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I know this tag but don't know how to use it exactly in this case. `<jsp:useBean id="quiz" class="Quiz"/>` then I could access to `${quiz.id}` but the Problem is I only have this quizList (a List with Quiz Objects). 
If I use `<jsp:useBean id="quizzes" class="Quiz"/>` I will only have access to a Quiz object but I want to have access to a property for example the id or title of one quiz.

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your clarification. You can use `forEach` tag to iterate over the list

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is, that I actually have no instances of the class Quiz. These objects are only saved in quizList. 
if I try
`<c:forEach items="${quizList}">`  
   `<c:out value="${quiz.id}"/>`     `Test<br>`
`</c:forEach>` I get no errors! And my JSP contains the word "Test" twice, which is okay because in my quizList there are two Quiz objects. In the head of my JSP I have both:
`<jsp:useBean id="quizzes" class="Quizzes" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="quiz" class="Quiz" scope="request"/>` Do you understand the problem?

Comment: I found the solution: in the head of the JSP I use both 
`<jsp:useBean id="quizzes" class="Quizzes" scope="request"/> <jsp:useBean id="quiz" class="Quiz" scope="request"/>` when iterrating  `<c:forEach items="${quizList}" varStatus="status">`  `${quizzes.quizlist[status.index].id}`    
`</c:forEach>`

Answer (score 0):

if you only need the Id per quiz, you can overwrite toString() function in the quiz:

```
public class Quiz{ 
  private int id;
  private String title;
  //getters and setters 
}

public class Quizzes{
  List<Quiz> quizList = new ArrayList<Quiz>;
  public Quizzes{
    //constructor to add Quiz objects to quizList
    Quiz curQuiz = new Quiz();
    ...
  }
  public List<Quiz> getQuizList(){
    return this.quizList;
  }

   @Override 
   public String toString(){
return getId();
  }

}
```

This way when you call toString() it will return appropriate Id:

```
Quiz.toString();
```

You can change your iterations to:

```
public List<Integer> getId(){
    List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ListIterator<Quiz> ir = quizlist.listIterator();
    while (ir.hasNext()){
        idList.add(ir.next().toString());
    }
    return idList;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but actually the quiz has several attributes I want to have access to