# Arraylist iterate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, arraylist

I have an array list with multiple value on jsp, and I want to iterate the array list. so that I can assign the values one by one in a textarea.

My jsp code:

```
<%
for(i=0;i<padetaillist.size();i++)
{
%>

<textarea id="txtpmhistory" class="txtpmhistoryy" name="txtpmhistory" 
         rows="1" cols="150" placeholder="Past Medical History">

  <%=padetaillist.get(i).getpmhistory()%></textarea>

<textarea id="txttobbaco" class="txttobbaco" name="txttobbaco" 
        rows="1" cols="150" placeholder="Tobbaco or Smoking">
```

I think this is wrong, I have several textareas but my jsp is not even displaying a single one.

So how can I iterate my arraylist so that I can assign the value to a text area and my jsp will display properly?  Is there any way that I can iterate my arraylist in JavaScript or with jquery and assign the value to a textarea?

Thanks
Rushang

Comment: Why are you declaring TextArea in your iteration? Are the number of textarea's that you are going to use fixed or variable?

Comment: my text area is fixed Rohan.

Comment: no its not change anything halex.

Comment: Do you get value in **padetaillist** in your jsp page?

Comment: Yes rohan i am getting the values in padetaillist

Comment: any errors in console? Such as, where is `i` defined? 
shouldn't you cast `padetaillist.get(i)` to the right object type so that you can then call `.getpmhistory()` on it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing it like this.

Use STL and use the core `taglib` and the `foreach` function

see this example

[<c:foreach jsp iterate over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053052/cforeach-jsp-iterate-over-list)