# How to populate a hidden HTML table with the result from the database?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP called `create-account.jsp` which collects a customer's details and sends the data to a Servlet. The Servlet inserts the customer's data into the database, queries the database add sets the results as request scoped attributes and the dispatches to `create-account.jsp`(same jsp). Now the inserted details must appear in a hidden html table in the jsp. How do I do it? Can any one help?

create-account.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Create New Account</title>
    <style>
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
            border-color: azure;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p align="right">Hi, ${sessionScope.user.userName} <a
        href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/logOut.do">logout</a></p>


<h2 align="center">Create New Account</h2>

<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create.do" method="post">
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DOB:(yyyy-mm-dd)</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="dob"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Balance:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="balance"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" name="create">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<p align="center" style="display: none">${requestScope.result} has been successfully inserted into the table</p>
<table id="hiddenTable" style="display: none" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
style="visibility: hidden;"
```

or

```
style="display:none;"
```

to hide the table.

for more info have a look at below links

- [CSS Display and Visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)
- [Show/Hide div javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-javascript)

---

How to show the result in table?

sample code:

Servlet:

```
public class Model{
     private String name;
     private String dob;
     private double balance;
     // getter and setter   
}

...

List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
//add the data in list

request.setAttribute("list",list);
```

JSP:

```
<c:if test="${not empty list}">
  <c:forEach var="ob" items="${list}">
     <tr>
       <td><c:out value="${ob.name}"/></td>
       <td><c:out value="${ob.dob}"/></td>
       <td><c:out value="${ob.balance}"/></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

For complete code have a look at [jsp iterate over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053052/cforeach-jsp-iterate-over-list)

Comment: How to unhide it later? Should I use one boolean attribute? How can I do it?

Comment: Look here [CSS Display and Visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I was trying the same thing.

Comment: My JavaScript was a little rustic. Thanks for the links.